# Optimize imports on the fly not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I want imports to be deleted immediately after they become unused, so I checked `Editor | General | Auto Import | Optimize imports on the fly`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If `Optimize imports on the fly` is selected as you have done, then unused imports should definitely be removed automatically, given that:

1. the file is recognized as a java file (it is located in a package under a `Source Route`.

and

2. the file is modified in some way (hit enter on a black line anywhere in the file, this will trigger imports optimization).

To optimize imports in many files at once, you can use ctrl+alt+O, or you can also tick *Optimize Imports* option when you check in files to source control (for example `svn`).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that under `Java | Imports`, the `Unused import (editor light)` inspection is enabled.